# Load lottie JSON file in Gridsome

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, lottie, gridsome

I try to use [lottie-vuejs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lottie-vuejs) in Gridsome but I don't succeed to import my animation file stored in **src/assets/animations/success.json**. I get a 404 error.

In my template I use lottie like that :

```
<template>
 </Layout>
  <lottie-animation path="./assets/animations/success.json" />
 </Layout>
</template>
```

In my gridsome file, I have tried to import my file with [Webpack](https://gridsome.org/docs/config/#configurewebpack) but it still not working.

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {

 configureWebpack: {
  module: {
   rules: [
     {
       type: 'javascript/auto',
       test: /\.json$/,
       include: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/assets/animations')],
       use: [
         {
           loader: 'file-loader',
         },
       ],
    },
  ],
 },
},
```